# Sticky navbar is not smooth, section jumps to the positition of the navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar and a section under it. The problem is when I scroll the navbar will stick but the section under it will basically move and it makes it not smooth and it is literally annoying.

I tried to figure it out but it is out of my capabilities. Also I know my code is kind of messy, but I tend to write this way and clean up once I'm done.

```js
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if (counter > 3) {
    counter = 1;
  }
}, 5000);

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-navigace");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    navbar.classList.remove("relative")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    navbar.classList.add("relative")
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#nav-logo {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-kontakt {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav-kontakt div {
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

#nav-navigace {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EBE76C;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 22px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#nav-navigace ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

#nav-navigace ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

#nav-navigace ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-navigace ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F0ED93;
}

#section-slider {}

#aktuality {
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.navigation-manual {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual-btn {
  border: 2px solid #EBE76C;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.manual-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.manual-btn:hover {
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio1:checked~.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio2:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio3:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#radio4:checked~.first {
  margin-left: -60%;
}

.navigation-auto {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 460px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-auto div {
  border: 2px solid #EBE76C;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navigation-auto div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#radio1:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn1 {
  background: #EBE76C;
}

#radio2:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn2 {
  background: #EBE76C;
}

#radio3:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn3 {
  background: #EBE76C;
}

#radio4:checked~.navigation-auto .auto-btn4 {
  background: #EBE76C;
}

#aktuality-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6;
  align-self: end;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div6 {
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div7 {
  grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 30px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.div8 {
  grid-area: 2 / 5 / 5 / 6;
  justify-self: center;
}

.div8 ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.div8 p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.div8 ul li {
  width: 165px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #EBE76C;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.div8 ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.div8 ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F58066;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<nav>
  <div id="nav-logo">
    <img src="./img/farnost-final.png" alt="Logo Farnost" height="130">
    <div id="nav-kontakt">
      <div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i> 890 989 098 <br>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i> email@email.cz</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-navigace" class="relative">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Uvod</a></li>
      <li><a href="">O Farnosti</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bohosluzby</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Ohlasky</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Zivot Farnosti</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Foto-video galerie</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Historie</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Farni casopis</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kontakty</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="section-slider">

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
      <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
      <div class="slide first">
        <img src="./img/slides/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="./img/slides/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="./img/slides/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="navigation-auto">
        <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
        <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-manual">
      <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
      <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<section id="aktuality">
  <div id="aktuality-wrapper">
    <div class="div1">
      <h1>Aktuality</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">Aktualita 1</div>
    <div class="div3">Aktualita 2</div>
    <div class="div4">Aktualita 3</div>
    <div class="div5">Aktualita 4</div>
    <div class="div6">Aktualita 5</div>
    <div class="div7">Aktualita 6</div>
    <div class="div8">
      <p>Potrebuji vyridit</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Krest</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Svatost smireni</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Euchrastie</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Birmovani</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Svatost</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Svatost</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pomazani nemocnych</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pohreb</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```